# Why is chrome slashing my HTTPS?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

In Chrome when I view my page the `https` in the URL has a red slash through it. When I click it, it says:

> Your connection to www.example.com is encrypted with 256-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. ...

I am not getting the mixed content warning in IE or FF.

Is there a way to get Chrome to tell you exactly what/where is causing the issue?

I am having trouble finding what is causing Chrome to throw a hissy fit. I searched my source for any http that does not contained http`s` but am not seeing any. It would be nice if there is an easy way to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Did you try clearing some of your browsing data?

Comment: @Moab I believe that was the issue.

Comment: Thanks, wonder why Randolph got 2 votes for not answering the question.

Comment: I haven't seen this but I would guess that it means that the encryption key is not signed digitally by a valid authority.

Comment: @Benoit It could also indicate that the site is serving mixed content (e.g. content is https, but images are http). Hard to tell without context. Raj, do you have a specific URL to give as an example?

Answer (score 11):

If you simply click on the lock symbol next to the struck through "https://", it will tell you what it means.

**EDIT:**

If you click on the lock symbol, it opens an information window that tells you about the encryption type of your connection to the website and about the giver of the certificate signature. It also tells you when you first visited the website.

Comment: +1 good point. An approach that can be useful other contexts as well.

Comment: This is a good point, and I'll agree that this isn't a very discoverable UI element, but this approach isn't very useful as an answer.  *What does it tell you*?

Answer (score 6):

Benoit is correct , a website with an **unverified** ssl certificate is shown as crossed out in google chrome.
You should be careful when entering data on such websites.
Generally though such sites are harmless.
But any website with an unverified SSL certificate asking sensitive data like credit card number  etc should be steered clear of.

Answer (score 6):

The dialog which appears after clicking the lock will bring you more detail.  At the moment, you can reproduce this behavior (safely) by navigating to https://superuser.com, but I'll walk you through the process and describe what the documentation means.  Clicking the lock produces the dialog:

[image]

*What do these mean* points to https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617, which reads:

> **The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected either high-risk insecure content on the page or problems with the site’s certificate.** Don’t enter sensitive information on this page. Invalid certificate or other serious https issues could indicate that someone is attempting to tamper with your connection to the site.

In this case, it's present because the (valid) certificate is for ***.stackexchange.com**, and **superuser.com** doesn't match.  That's *a problem with the site's certificate*.  It's not a big deal; you really don't need SSL for most purposes on Superuser, and I'm fairly confident that the people behind *.stackexchange.com are the same people behind Superuser.  In other cases with this same cause, such as https://j.randomsite.com signing itself with the certificate used for https://mail.google.com, the warning would indicate that something fishy was going on.Other reasons for this dialog (*high-risk insecure content* or different *problems with the site's certificate*) could also be malicious, so don't click through or enter sensitive information without being aware of what's actually going on.

---

Contrary to what other authors have written, this does *not* indicate mixed content.  It might indicate incorrectly mixed content, but normally, that would produce a yellow lock and no slash:

[image]

about which the support link says:

> The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page. Be careful if you’re entering sensitive information on this page. Insecure content can provide a loophole for someone to change the look of the page.